# OTRS Mailfetching issue

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, otrs

I have issue with OTRS version 6 which is running on ubuntu 16.04.

OTRS didn't fetch the mail properly whenever i tried to fetch the mail it through below error

" **OTRS-otrs.Console.pl-Maint::PostMaster::MailAccountFetch-77[5799]: [Error][Kernel::System::Daemon::DaemonModules::BaseTaskWorker::_HandleError][Line:52]: There was an error executing Execute() in Kernel::System::Console::Command::Maint::PostMaster::MailAccountFetch: Error: Timeout of 600 seconds reached, killing child process!**"

I tried below steps:

1. Tried to reconfigure fetchmail:bin not success
2. Tried to add new param in Daemon: "ArtticlIndex rebuild" add new param "--force-pid"
   3.Restart the server from remote console

How to fix this issue? please guide me on this.

Comment: You should not use otrs 6 anymore, that has known security issues. I would recoment switching to znuny, which is a fork that is in constant development. They have a discord server, where the developers will guide you trough your problem. https://www.znuny.org/de/news/community-discord-server